# meaning of "that" in "that much better"

Tags: word-meaning

What's the function of "that" in the following? Is it a misprint or something?

> "I've had my notebook with me and I've written down 30 or 40 little things that will make the experience for the next person who goes to space with us **that** much better," he said.

Answer (score 4):

The adverb ***that*** here is an instance of [anaphoric reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaphora_(linguistics)), as it refers to those ***30 or 40 little things*** written in the notebook from the precedent sentence. ***That*** is an intensifier of ***much***, and it means:

> to such an extent
>
> - a nail about ***that*** long ([M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/that))

In this example, you could picture the speaker showing [with his hand](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/that_4) the length referred to by ***that***, which is used deictically. Here is what [CaGEL](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/cambridge-grammar-of-the-english-language/A78402ABF5176AD283494180BCA2046F) has to say about this:

> *Demonstratives* [both *this* and *that*] can be used ***deictically*** not only to pick out physical objects in the
> situation of utterance, but also ***in reference to properties of such objects or to actions
> taking place or other abstract features of the situation of utterance***:
>
> - I've never seen a computer
>   ***this*** *small* before.
>
> Deictic demonstratives are often accompanied by indexing acts such
> as pointing *[in this example to a surprisingly small computer].* (see p. 1505)

[OxfordL](https://www.google.com/search?q=that%20meaning&sxsrf=ALeKk03yiT9k71-Lqnsn39KIMGgnlaA5tg%3A1628082058032&source=hp&ei=iY8KYYasPIWOhbIP05-smAQ&iflsig=AINFCbYAAAAAYQqdmuX_ow31k4lekBj5txz3EUgBDU7Q&oq=that%20mean&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAEYADIICAAQgAQQsQMyBAgAEEMyBAgAEEMyBAgAEEMyBQguEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCC4QgAQ6BAgjECc6CggAELEDEIMBEEM6DgguEIAEELEDEMcBEKMCOhEILhCABBCxAxCDARDHARDRAzoECC4QQzoLCAAQgAQQsQMQgwE6CwguEIAEEMcBEK8BOggILhCABBCxAzoNCAAQgAQQhwIQsQMQFFC3BFjkD2DUGGgAcAB4AYABwASIAcwakgELMC4zLjEuMi4yLjKYAQCgAQGwAQA&sclient=gws-wiz) defines the adverb ***that*** as

> to such a degree; ***so***.
>
> - I wouldn't go that far.

In your sentence

> X will make the experience for the next person who goes to space with us ***that much** better*,

*that much* intensifies the comparative ***better*** by how much? By  ***that** much*:

> ***The experience*** for the next person who goes to space with us ***will be improved by the knowledge acquired from the 30 or 40 little things*** I have written down in the notebook.